# Savvio disk in HP ML350 G5 server

Tags: hp, hard-drive, seagate

Has anyone got real-life experience with using a Seagate Savvio disk in a HP ML350 G5 server.
There are two things I'm worried about.

1. Will it physically fit the tray, can the tray be inserted and will the SAS-connectors fit the connectors on the HD back plane.
2. Will the RAID adapter accept it.

I have posted similar questions before and have gotten fairly fluffy answers. So I'm hoping someone have actually tried it with the same server (or at least just a fairly similar HP server with 2.5" disk trays).

Answer (score 2):

HP buy their disks from the usual suspects (seagate, WD, Hitachi etc.) but in almost every case they put their own firmware on them. Physically they'll fit if you have the mount for the drive - that's the tricky bit as they don't sell 'blanks'. After that it's down to whether or not the actual code on your disk controllers is happy to work with non-HP disks - some seem to be ok, others lock you out - you really have to just try it and gauge your own very of the stability.

Comment: Yes, the special trays are a joke, but I have finally managed to get hold of some extras after a disk crash and having purchased an additional spare.

Answer (score 1):

The SAS and SATA backplanes are a universal standard (if either HP or Seagate decided to change it, nothing would ever work in their devices), so there's no doubt about whether or not it will physically fit. It will fit.

Unfortunately I can only give a fuzzy answer on the 2nd point - it should accept it, but I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Ok, thx. Guess it's gonna be a bit of a gamble. Although the Savvio disks are half the price of HP, it's still a reasonably large amount of money if it turns out not to work at all.